# Async operations architecture between providers and calling pages

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, ionic-framework, promise

I'm flummoxed on the best way to use providers to get and subsequently forward asynchronous data... and, unfortunately, I don't know what I don't know, so my question is nebulous at best.

What is the best way to create an architecture for database or other async operations that keeps all database/http/etc calls together, but allows for async operations on the calling page itself?  For example, I'd like to call "this.provider.getDataFromDatabase()" and then use the data in the same page.

I guess I could boil the question down to, "Where do you put the .then()s?"

Here are some examples of some things I've played with:

**1. Promise wrapped in a promise method-**  In the provider I've written promises wrapped in promises, where the inside promise is the database/http/etc call, and the outside promise is the function that the calling page will use to coordinate async functions (using .then())

***.then() locations*** - one .then() for the async call is in the provider. The other .then() is in the calling page that handles the wrapper
***Pro -*** I'm able to keep all async operations completely in the provider, and I'm still able to coordinate operations in the calling page.
***Con -*** It seems unnecessarily complicated, and I keep thinking I'm smacking up against a "promise anti-pattern"

```
public getPeople() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.storage.executeSql("SELECT * FROM people", []).then((data) => 
                { 
                  console.log(data); 
                  resolve(people); 
                }, (error) => { reject(error); }); 
         }); 
    }
```

**2. Return a promise method-** In the provider, the code is there just to set up the database/http/etc promise, that is just returned to the calling page where it uses .then() to coordinate operations.

***.then() locations -*** only one in the calling page itself.
***Pro -*** Simpler code in provider. 
***Con -*** The idea of a data provider seems to be spoiled since the actual functions are in the calling page.  That seems to blur the line between provider and calling page.
Code Example

```
public getPeople() {
            return this.storage.executeSql("SELECT * FROM people", []) 
            }
```

**3. EventEmitters method -** All of the code for performing an async operations is written in the provider. The .then() is in the provider and passes the results back to the page via an event.  The subscribe event, then, coordinates actions in the page itself.

***.then() locations -*** only one in the provider 
***Pro -*** Simpler code in provider.  Simpler code in calling page. All async operations in provider, and page specific custom code in page. 
***Con -*** The code is a little harder to follow in the page since the calling function and the subscribe function aren't "together." Additionally, I always feel like I'm going to get myself in trouble by sending data to an unloaded page. 
Code Example

```
public getPeople() {
        this.storage.executeSql("SELECT * FROM people", []).then((data) => 
            { 
              this.events.publish('getPeople', data);        
            } 
        }
```

I'm curious what the best practice is. I'm leaning to the emitter method, but I don't know if there's some hidden issue that I haven't yet encountered.  Thank you in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provider or service or any other class,
must return a value or Promise or Observable in getter.

hope code example will be helpful

```
class Product{}

class ProductsService{
  getProduct(){
    return new Product();
    //or return Observable<Product>
    //or return Promise<Product>;
  }
}

class ProductPresenter{

  private product: Product;

  constructor(private _productService:ProductsService){
    //so here must be sync or async way of getting a product to show
    this.product = _productService.getProduct();
    //or _productService.getProduct().then(() => {});
    //or _productService.getProduct().subscribe(() => {});
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok... So, it seems that for a data provider, that you'd go with the #1 Promise inside a promise method.  That is, in the provider, you'd create a promise that is handled by the calling page. The innards of that promise would be the async database promise

Comment: Sometimes you may need number of promises or other async data to be resolved at once, before page initialization.

So in your case page can have some absration, like angular2 resolvers.

Comment: In 1 and 2 you are doing almost the same. Cuz somewhere in code it will be getProduct().then(() => {});
So 1 is same as sql.then(() => return Promise.resolve(data)),
as sql call already returns a Promise

Comment: yes.  I agree.  1, 2 and 3 are doing the same thing.  The only difference is how the information is passed between the provider and the calling page.  That's the nature of my confusion... which is the best way? (or are there others that I'm missing?)

Comment: You must collect data not inside promises.
Somewhere in page 
Promise.all(getProducts(), getComments(), getUsers()).then(() => {
});